# Source file for Firefox's SSL error

Tags: firefox, ssl

In Linux Firefox, if in case there is any error related to SSL/TLS, which source file does it refer to in order to generate the error code and pop up window (or error page)?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Ok, I'll try. I'm looking for the source file that maintain the error codes and error messages that relates to SSL. I need to create a new error message that falls under this group. This is my first time looking at the source of Firefox and NSS, I'm terribly lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not clear what exactly you're looking for since the implementation behind this is scattered among many source files, but I'll show you how to start.

Mozilla has MXR, which can be used to quickly search through their code. So we take the caption of a visible element on the page you're interested in, e.g. "I understand the risks" button and search for it: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=I%20understand%20the%20risks. You find the only hit, which defines the string and you'll need to search again to find where that string is actually used: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=certerror.expert.heading.

This gets us to http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/certerror/content/aboutCertError.xhtml which falls under the definition "Source file for Firefox’s SSL error", but may be not the end of your journey :)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm using MXR now.